# How to avoid Interbase error 'Column Unknown'

Tags: sql, interbase

There are 2 tables in InterBase 2020 db: t1 and t2.

```
t1 fields: i1 integer,
           f1 float
t2 fields: i2 integer,
           f2 float
```

Derived table (dt1) works properly on IB and on FB, but this full code returns an error **only on IB** server:

> 'Column Unknown F1'

```
select
    i1 as i3,
    sum(f1) as f3
    
From
      (select
        i1,
        sum(f1) as f1
         from t1
          group by i1
    
        union all
    
       select
        i2,
        sum(f2) as f2
         from t2
          group by i2) dt1
 group by i1
```

How to avoid this error?

Comment: Try changing the output names so you can pinpoint the error.

Comment: @shawnt00  I changed names but the same error occurs.  Did you mean this? 
select
    sum(i1) as i3,
    sum(f5) as f3

From
      (select
        i1,
        sum(f1) as f5
         from t1
          group by i1

        union all

       select
        i2,
        sum(f2) as f2
         from t2
          group by i2) dt1
 group by i1
Result: 'column unknown F5'.i.e. alias is unknown

Comment: Yes. I'm not familiar with your platforms though. Can you specify aliases this way?: `dt1(i1, F1)`

Comment: @shawnt00 I tried this: "column unknown: dt1.f1"

Comment: Does it work if you just try to sum i1 and remove the second column?

Comment: Btw I did check some documentation that says "derived column lists" are not valid.

Comment: Other documentation says that unions in derived tables are valid.

Comment: @shawnt00 I tried write code as in embarcadero docs is described: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/InterBase/2020/en/SELECT#Derived_Tables_.28SELECT_FROM_SELECT.29 (section "Examples With Derived Tables")

Comment: i think your query is invalid: you have to make your mind what `i1` is: either `sum(i1)` or  `group by i1` but not both. Also does Interbase 2020 support CTE instead of derived tables? In CTEs you can explicitly name synthetic columns.

Comment: If your question is about InterBase, then please don't tag Firebird. Even if they share a common ancestry, they diverged 21 years ago, so they are not the same product.

Comment: @Arioch'The  'what i1 is: either sum(i1) or group by i1 but not both'.  not sum. it's goods ID in  t1 (incomes) and t2(sales) tables. I must group by ID.

Comment: then change your query, so it would not be `sum(i1)`, change it both in the question above and in the interbase, and try again

Comment: @Arioch'The thank you. there was an error. I correct it but nothing changed.  I'm doing everything as derived table's using  is describred in official docs about IB:  https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/InterBase/2020/en/SELECT#Examples_With_Derived_Tables.

Comment: @Arioch'The this is full sql-code  which works correctly in FB: select
    G.ID,  G.NAME,  dt2.A1 as INC, dt2.B1 as SALES,  dt2.ostatok as RESTS FROM Good g 
Join (select   ID,   sum(A) as A1 , sum(B) as B1,  sum(A-B) as ostatok  from  (select         ID, sum(f1) as A,  cast(0 as float)as B  from t1 group by ID union all  select ID,  cast(0 as float), sum(f2) as B  from t2  group by ID) as  dt1
   group by ID)as dt2 On G.ID=dt2.ID Order by G.Name

Comment: Just a random guess... Since it seems Interbase does not support CTE (not documented at least by our link), try to formalize your inner select-union-select as a persistent `VIEW`, which has "official" column names, then select from that VIEW instead. Also think about removing `sum` from the inner selects, as you do summing on outer level anyway. Not sure it would make the query faster, but a slim chance it would randomly workaround the deficiency in Interbase SQL parser.

Comment: you may also try to replace `union` with `full outer join`, something like that:

`select coalesce(st1.i1, st2.i2) as id, coalesce(st1.f1, 0) + coalesce(st2.f2, 0) as the_sum
From   (select i1, sum(f1) as f1 from t1 group by i1 ) st1   full outer join  (select i2, sum(f2) as f2 from t2 group by i2) st2 on st2.i2 = st1.i1 )`

Comment: Again, i can't say how that would affect the query speed and disk temporary volume usage...  i wonder would would be query plans in FB for both initial and this query, would there be indexed merge of sorted-by-index streams or unsorted operations...

Comment: @Arioch'The unfortunately IB 2020 crashed and I'm not able test you code. I have only IB 2009 which didn't support derived tables. I'll try as soon as install IB 2020 and write result here. Thank you.

Comment: Wow!  IB is getting better by the year... When they introduced monitoring tbales (TMP$xxxx) it seemed they got the steam and Firebird is dragging behind, but look where they are now... They said, around 1.5 FB spend a lot of time restructuring and rewriting code, paying out a share of "tech debt", invisible to user, dormant as it appeared. But seemed that paid off in the long run. It is up to you, but is it pays to keep support for a database engine so fragile and feature-less? Database should be reliable above everything else and "IB 2020 crashed" to me sounds a blocker.

Comment: `IB 2009 which didn't support derived tables` - then do the `VIEW` like i said before. Or why would you support ib2020 but not ib2009? Frankly, if you want to support both families, i bet you have to roll back to features available in FB 1.x / IB 7.x, and then account for pro-standard anti-legacy behavior changes in FB 2.0. While founding fundamentals are still the same in IB and FB, the "implementation details", the particularities diverged a lot indeed.

Comment: Anyway, with or without ib2020, i still mantain you have to test `full outer join` query on Firebird along with your original query on the same database, both "cold" and "warmed up", focusing upon query plans and performance counters. If that query would turn out prohibitively slow - you would not have to bother a slightest whether ib2020 can execute it or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your outer query has only knowhow of your derived table column names. So, qualify your column names during the derived table definition of "dt1", as such; "dt1 (i1, f1)".

```sql
select
    i1 as i3,
    sum(f1) as f3
    
From
      (select
        i1,
        sum(f1) as f1
         from t1
          group by i1
    
        union all
    
       select
        i2,
        sum(f2) as f2
         from t2
          group by i2) dt1 (i1, f1)
 group by i1;
```

Comment: Sriram Balasubramanian, it works fine. Thank you!!!